# How to register a Firebase user from Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building an app in Laravel that integrates with a mobile app, and the mobile app requires Firebase.

How do I go about creating a Firebase user with Laravel? I know there is an unofficial [Laravel Firebase package](https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase), but I haven't seen anything in the documentation about registering users.

Comment: This might help you https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/user-management.html#create-a-user

Answer (score 0):

You could use kreait/firebase php package.It is the popular one to deal with firebase from php as an admin,You could create update delete read data and send fcm notification.
All api crud described in their documentation.
So You could install it from packagist:

https://packagist.org/packages/kreait/firebase-php

Answer (score 0):

I have used https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase before and it works quite well. Checkout the documentation to see how it works.